# EPSG code as dynamic text in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, cartography

Is it possible to get ArcGIS to show the EPSG code for a coordinate system as dynamic text?

The default text is quite verbose (see below), and I think just showing the "Coordinate System" is probably enough. However, it would be quite useful if I could also show "EPSG:32632" in addition to this.

```
Coordinate System: WGS 1984 UTM Zone 32N
Projection: Transverse Mercator
Datum: WGS 1984
False Easting: 500,000.0000
False Northing: 0.0000
Central Meridian: 9.0000
Scale Factor: 0.9996
Latitude Of Origin: 0.0000
Units: Meter
```

The [documentation for ArcGIS 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000013000000) doesn't mention it, but I'm hoping it's just been missed out, or there is a work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have search around a little but the only reference I can find to being able to add the factory code as dynamic text is with the Production Mapping - MPS Atlas extension

http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//019t0000003z000000

Comment: Thanks Peter. It looks like this is the answer. It's a shame so much basic functionality is locked up in extensions and licence levels I don't have access too. It's all about the $$$...